# Wordpress' get_posts and pagination not working

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

I have a code in a page template that looks like this (obviously first I set up IDs of categories):

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;         
global $post; 
$myposts = get_posts("cat=$catIDs&posts_per_page=12&paged=" . $paged);
?>
<div class="column-odd">
    <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($myposts as $post) :
            if($i%2 != 0) :
                setup_postdata($post);
                //output odd post
            endif;
            $i++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
</div>
<div class="column-even">
    <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($myposts as $post) :
            if($i%2 == 0) :
                setup_postdata($post);
                //output even post
            endif;
            $i++;
        endforeach;
    ?>
</div>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <?php
         if($link = get_previous_posts_link("« Poprzednia strona")) 
                echo '<li class="prev">'.$link.'</li>';
         if($link = get_next_posts_link("Następna strona »")) 
                echo '<li class="next">'.$link.'</li>';

        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that `get_next_posts_link` is not returning anything. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work with get_posts. You need to use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Example_2). I think it should work with the same arguments. edit: you'll also need to save it as $myposts = query_posts( ... ), since you're using two foreach loops like this.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to add the following line:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=post&paged='. get_query_var('paged')); ?>
```

just before your get_posts() loop starts.

Full article here: http://blog.onireon.it/wordpress-get_posts-and-pagination-posts-are-correctly-displayed-but-no-pagination-links-are-showing/